# Reactdropzone error while using react-dropzone

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

I am trying to use react-dropzone in my project but got error that does not render the reactDropzone component. I tried this:

```
import ReactDropzone from 'react-dropzone';
export class BankingDetail extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ReactDropzone
        accept="image/*"
        onDrop={()=>console.log("this.onPreviewDrop")}
      >
        Drop an image, get a preview!
      </ReactDropzone>
    );
  }
}
```

But got an error as shown in the file:
[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The usage is quite different then your implementation https://react-dropzone.netlify.com/

Answer (score 0):

You try to pass a string as children props. But it takes function as children props. Read more about this component [here](https://react-dropzone.netlify.com/#proptypes)